# Loop while for array on php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, while-loop

Why this loop doesn't work? When I check with    `echo vardump($tablesliders);`  the array tablesliders only have inserted one element, the last element of the query. The query is correct.

```
while($row_Slider=mysql_fetch_array($Query_Sliders)){   
    $QuestionID=$row_Slider['QuestionIDFK'] ;
    $AnswerID=$row_Slider['AnswerIDPK'] ;
    $AnswerValue=$row_Slider['AnswerValue'] ;
    $tablesliders = array (
            "QuestionID"  => array($k => $QuestionID),
            "$AnswerID" => array($k => $AnswerID),
            "$AnswerValue"   => array($k => $AnswerValue)
             );
        $k=k+1;
}
```

How could I re-write the code using `foreach` loop ?
I am very tired with it because with `mysql_fetch_array($Query_Sliders)` syntax don't let me run.

Comment: The reason is you are actually writing over the array every time. You should do it like: $loopArray = array(); then do your while thing on $loopArray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are resetting the $tablesliders variable on each loop.

Try making it into an array and incrementing it on each loop.

```
$tablesliders = array();

while($row_Slider=mysql_fetch_array($Query_Sliders)){
    $QuestionID=$row_Slider['QuestionIDFK'] ;
    $AnswerID=$row_Slider['AnswerIDPK'] ;
    $AnswerValue=$row_Slider['AnswerValue'] ;

    $tablesliders[] = array (
        "QuestionID"  => array([$k] => $QuestionID),
        "$AnswerID" => array([$k] => $AnswerID),
        "$AnswerValue"   => array([$k] => $AnswerValue)
    );
    $k=k+1;
}
```

Although actually looking at your script I can't imagine that is how you would want it to work (each array would only have the one question, answer and value rather than an array of them all).

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting it on each iteration, you need to append to it:

```
$tablesliders[] = array (
```

The `[]` appends to the array, you can also use `array_push()`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to push each element in the array like this:

```
$tablesliders = array();

while($row_Slider=mysql_fetch_array($Query_Sliders)){

    $QuestionID=$row_Slider['QuestionIDFK'] ;
    $AnswerID=$row_Slider['AnswerIDPK'] ;
    $AnswerValue=$row_Slider['AnswerValue'] ;

        $tablesliders[] = array (
        "QuestionID"  => $QuestionID,
        "AnswerID" => $AnswerID,
        "AnswerValue"   => $AnswerValue
                 );
        $k=k+1;
}
```

That is making some assumptions about what you want your keys and values to be.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, I don't understand what `$k` is used for? But this is how I'd build an array using a foreach.

```
foreach($row_Slider as $key => $value){
    array_push($tablesliders, $key => $value);
}
print_r($tablesliders);
//should print 
/* ARRAY( 'QuestionIDFK' => 'value',
          'AnswerIDPK' => 'value',
          'AnswerValues => 'value'
        );
```

But obviously this will enter each entry into the array.